# @available(*, deprecated) translation to objc?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have framework where I need to mark a method deprecated written in Swift. My question is does swift @available(*, deprecated) attribute translates into ObjC also? If someone using my framework is using it in objc will it the translated swift-h file show this method deprecated?

If not what is the way to mark a swift method to be deprecated in swift and objc both?